# draw bitmap onto form background from "outside"

Tags: vb.net, forms, graphics

I would like to draw a bitmap onto a form, but not from within the form.
I would rather like to do something like this:

```
myBitmap.DrawUnscaled(frmOverlay.DefInstance.Graphics)
```

But it looks so weird to me, and it is surely not correct.
What would be a good way to do that, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Right, it is not correct.  Which is usually the way it goes when you are trying to do something that doesn't make sense.  The next time the form repaints itself, the image will be gone.  Assigning the form's BackgroundImage property is an obvious approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply expose the Image property of the destination form:

```
Class destForm

    Public WriteOnly Property SetImage As Image
        Set(value As Image)
            Me.BackgroundImage = value
            Me.Invalidate
        End Set
    End Property

    '...

End Class
```

Then from the form/location you want to set the image from you call (you can use both `Bitmap` and `Image` objects here):

```
destForm.SetImage = myBitmap
```

You can optionally take a parameter on the property to set fill mode etc. (not shown in this example).

Comment: I don't see why "SetImage" should be a property, I guess "sub" would be more adequate. Anyway, a great help! Thank you!

Comment: @tmighty SetImage it was the best I could come up with on the fly :-) Just change to what you want, if you want to use a sub instead it's up to you. The common way is to use a property for these things.